# How to set Google Translate page (user interface) always to be in English language

Tags: google-translate

On this page - https://translate.google.com/ - I see the serbian cyrilic language as the **interface language**, probably because my IP address is in Serbia at the moment.

I want this page to always be in English, regardless where I actually am.

Is it possible and how?

*By the way Chrome is set in English and this works, but especially the above page is on serbian cyrilic*.

Comment: Are you logged in to Google? For me, it always remembers the last used translation languages. (?)

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in. It's not problem with translation language but with user interface language

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can set/override the *interface language* by specifying the appropriate [IETF language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) in the `hl` URL parameter.

So, for English, this would be:

```
https://translate.google.com/?hl=en
```

(For Serbian cyrillic language you would use `sr-Cyrl`.)

Comment: that's it, solved. But still strange, isn't it? Default language should be english if not specified (`https://translate.google.com`)

Comment: I would agree. I don't think the language should default based on the IP address (apart from being potentially inaccurate as a location indicator, _location_ is not necessarily an indicator of _language_ anyway). If anything, it should default based on the value of the `Accept-Language` HTTP request header - what is your browser reporting for this? (It's possible that both Serbian Cyrillic _and_ English are "accepted", but Serbian Cyrillic has a higher _priority_?)